# xcconfig option in xcodebuild command

Tags: ios, xcode, cmd, xcodebuild

I have created an app in IOS and want to build and run it through command line. The xcodebuild command helps in building the app and its basic syntax is as follows:

```
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration Release -xcconfig "${BUILD_SETTINGS_FILE_PATH}"
```

Each target will contain its product name and other build settings. Now I don't want to take the product name/build settings specified in xcode target, but rather through some external file which can contain build settings. So, i tried using the `-xcconfig` option but I am not clear with its implementation. What kind of file it should be and how the path to the file be configured?. The official documentation also doesn't seem to be too clear.

Comment: See this on how to export xcconfig file from command line with xcodebuild http://stackoverflow.com/a/20862973/571227

Answer (score 1):

[xcodebuild PRODUCT_NAME argument affects all targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357066/xcodebuild-product-name-argument-affects-all-targets)

.xcconfig file can be created using Xcode and the format of providing value is:

```
CUSTOM_CFBundleVersion = 3.0.
CUSTOM_CFBundleShortVersionString = 3.0
```